# How to add custom class in body tag on form submit?

Tags: theming

I have created custom module with custom form, in which I have added input type select. Form submission is working fine, but I wanted set select option value as custom class for BODY tag.

Comment: As per @samzha suggestion I used **Switch Theme** module and it's work fine for me, the only thing I need to create different themes for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add through custom hook.

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'new-class';
}
```

**OR**

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $path = 'your-drupal-page';
  if (drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], $path) || drupal_match_path(drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']), $path)) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'page-my-css-class';
  }
}
```

If you have any query related how to create then you can check this [LINK](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3497/how-to-add-a-custom-class-in-the-body-tag-in-your-drupal-site).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but how do I get value of Selected option instead of 'new-class'?

Comment: Means you want to select any option default SELECTED ???

Comment: I am trying to create option for user to change theme color using select list.

Comment: Ok now I understand. You have some themes (Color) in your site & you want a select option & through this select option you need to jump one theme to another. Am I right ??

Comment: Yes, but instead of changing theme I want add class in Body tag

Comment: Try to use **Switch Theme** module or you have to use JS.

Comment: Another question is when do you want the change to take place? After form submit or before form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Seems a pretty odd request and there might be a better way, please explain exactly what you're trying to achieve so a better solution could be offered.

Based upon your original post this could probably be achieved with the combination of [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Context Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_rules) & [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)